# Why are entries and pickers disabled in some screens in iOS version of my Xamarin.Forms app?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, picker

My problem is that I have one screen in my iOS version of a Xamarin.Forms app where the entries and bindable pickers are not responding, like if they are not enabled. In other screens they are working fine.

Curious thing is that this faliling screen is working fine in the UWP version.

Any idea? All help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any code associated to this? What does it look like? We need a bit more information than this.

Comment: How about adding some code, screenshots etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the problem is finally fixed.

The error was that I had an AbsolutLayout containing an Activity indicator over all the page controls (transparent), and in the UWP version works OK, but in the iOS version it causes that the buttons are not allowed to be clicked (because in reality you are clicking in the transparent AbsolutLayout over all, not on the controls below)... I have changed the AbsolutLayout to fix this.

I hope this can help others with the same error.
Thanks.